# How to execute xml nodes available under respective attribute values using C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have different xml nodes available under different attribute values in xml.
I would like to execute the respective nodes present under respective attribute values in xml.
But i am facing an issue that everytime i am able to identify and change the attribute values but all the time the nodes available under first attribute value are getting executed.
Please find my code as follows:

```
try
            {
                XmlDocument XDoc = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLFromFile(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile);
                XmlNodeList Update_Bugs = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Bugs");


                string attrVal_TestCondition = "";
                string attrVal_Name = "";

                for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
                {
                    attrVal_TestCondition = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
                    attrVal_Name = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["Name"].Value;

                    foreach (string AttValue in attrVal_TestCondition.Split(','))
                    {
                         //Step1: Create Bugs
                        List<string> BugWSResponseList1 = new List<string>();
                        Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + " : START : Creation of a set of Bugs via bug.Add API");
                        BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile, DateTimeStamp);
```

Please find the sample xml as follows in which i have two different attribute values available under `TestCondition` as `STATE` and `STATUS` whereas when my loop brings the second attribute value which is `'STATUS'` in my case then the xml nodes available under `STATE` are getiing executed.Thats My problem actually.Please suggest.

```
<DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name="Testing 11" TestCondition="STATE">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>NeedsReview</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  <Bugs Name="Testing 22" TestCondition="STATUS">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>NeedsReview</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
</DrWatson>
```

I am creating some bugs using the following part of code :

```
 BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile, DateTimeStamp);
```

Please note that when this part of code is being approached after picking up the second attribute value present in the xml which is `STATUS` in my case then it executes the same set of nodes `<Bug><Bug>` which belongs to the first attribute value i.e. `STATE` in my xml.

Comment: within the code you posted i cannot see the part that would actually be responsible for "executing" anything - so no idea why it always uses the first node

Comment: @olydis Please find the updated information above.

Comment: @olydis i have updated the required information in this thread above.Can you please suggest something.

Comment: sorry but I still cannot see where you are trying to make sure to read from the node you get the attribute from... the line you posted **reopens** the file instead of working on the XML you are traversing

Comment: @olydis yes i guess thats the problem. can you please suggest how can i perform that as i want to execute the respective nodes for attribute values in xml.

Comment: @olydis can you please suggest how can i select the respective nodes for each attribute values in xml.I really dont know how i can do it.

Comment: well under `Update_Bugs[m]` you already have the respective node - and you already used it to find out attributes! Read the documentation of `XmlNode` although you already used its methods successfully! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx